# UINavigationController: How do I delete a view of a stack

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Let say here is my stack layout

```
View3     --> Top of the stack
View2
View1
HomeView  --> Bottom of the stack
```

So I am in `View3` now, if I click the `Home` button, I want to load `HomeView`, meaning that I need to pop `View3`, `View2`, and `View1`. But if I pop `View3`, `View2` will be displayed. I dont want that. I want `View3`, `View2`, and `View1` be removed, and `HomeView` will be displayed. Any idea how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToRootViewControllerAnimated:) to get to the root viewcontroller. This would pop out all the view controllers in the stack except the root view controller. In your case, this would be the *HomeView*.

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

To get to a specific view in the stack, you can use [popToViewController:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:) Assuming you want to pop the third viewcontroller (from bottom up). In your case, this would be *view2*:

```
NSArray* viewControllersInStack = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController* targetViewController = [viewControllersInStack objectAtIndex:2];
[self.navigationController popToViewController:targetViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have homeview as root in the example, but it is not the case in my code. TYVM :)

Comment: I try that, but it said `HomeView` is undefined, which make sense since I am in `View3` so I dont have reference to `HomeView`, is that right?

Comment: Yes you need a reference to the `HomeView`, and you can get that via the `self.navigationController.viewControllers` property

Comment: I try to set the reference but it does not work. Access it via any array, well it messy, since u have to keep track of the index. Would you kindly enough to post some sample code on how to do PopToViewController, with access via reference, please?

Answer (score 2):

Use [popToViewController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:)

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:homeView animated:YES];
```

Comment: How does it work? The documentation said you pop to a specific viewController, but I keep getting seg fault. U think u can give me a quick sample code?

Comment: It's pop the view until the specific viewController is on the top of the stack. Can you post an error log and some of your code as well ?

Comment: Well, let say that I am in `aViewController` (assume that it already on the stack) , I push `bViewController`, then in `bViewController`, I `popToViewController:aViewController`, well but it said `aViewController` is undefined, which make sense since I am in `bViewController` now. I dont have reference to `aViewController`. Am I missing something?

Comment: That's right, as @Ronnie Liew said. You need a reference.

I usually pass this job to my delegate which have references to all of the related viewcontrollers. You can do this by [Protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c).  (in your case, try `informal`)

Answer (score 0):

use...

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];