# How can I break the "navigation stack" in a Cocoa Touch App?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm currently trying to create a navigation based application, pushing views to change the screen content. I'm trying to set up a button which can allow me to "restart" from the first screen, but I can't figure out a way to do that.

If I "push" the first view, there will be a "back" button, and I'll just have another piece on the view stack.
In fact, I'm want to reinitialize that stack.

Is it possible ? (Am I clear ? English is not my first language :) )

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595049/uinavigationcontroller-how-do-i-delete-a-view-of-a-stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To navigate to the 1st view in navigation stack (i.e. to the root controller) you can simply with just one call:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you want to change root controller as well I think you can do that using `setViewControllers:animated:` method

Comment: Thanks for the second tip, it'll me a lot :)